# How to use CSS to make div elements appear when you hover over different parts an p element?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone can help with this problem, I'm having with doing hovering over different parts of an p element? I not sure, if I have this coded right or not but I been looking around at different answers to similar problems but none of them are working for me. I have a menu and I'm trying to get the div to show up behind each word. Right now I have the options in one paragraph and so far it only shows up on the "Home" option. Can anyone please tell me if I need to re-code my menu to get it to work or if it possible in the current way I coded?

Thanks

**Update #2**: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I have choose MichaelvE's idea as my solution to my question. Now I just need to fix my layout to the way I had it before I used this new code. Thank again to everyone for the help!

HTML:

```
<p id="Ms" align="center" class="m1">Home</a>
<a class="m2" href="Bio.html">About</a> 
<a class="m3" href="Services.html">Services</a>
<a class="m4" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
</p>

<div><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL1" /></div>
<div><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL2" /></div>
<div><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL3" /></div>
<div><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL4" /></div>
```

CSS coding:

```
.HL1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 330px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 565px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 800px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1050px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.m1:Hover + .HL1 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m2:Hover + .HL2 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m3:Hover + .HL3 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m4:Hover + .HL4 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: I believe you are using the + operator wrong. `+` in CSS means the first element is directly before the second element. So, the last 4 CSS rules don't mean anything because the `m1, m2, m3...` classes are grouped together and separated from the `HL1, HL2, HL3...` classes in the HTML. Like @MichaelvE said, use the `~` selector instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sibling selectors need to have the same parent. So place the links and the images within the same parent like:

```
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <a id="Ms" class="m1">Home</a>    
    <a class="m2" href="Bio.html">About</a> 
    <a class="m3" href="Services.html">Services</a>
    <a class="m4" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

    <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL1" />
    <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL2" />
    <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL3" />    
    <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL4" />
</div>
```

Also, use the general sibling selector ~ instead of the adjacent sibling selector +:

```
.m1:Hover ~ .HL1 {
visibility: visible;}
```

**Full Example**

```css
.HL1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 330px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 565px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 800px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1050px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.m1:Hover ~ .HL1 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m2:Hover ~ .HL2 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m3:Hover ~ .HL3 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m4:Hover ~ .HL4 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
        <a id="Ms" class="m1">Home</a>    
        <a class="m2" href="Bio.html">About</a> 
        <a class="m3" href="Services.html">Services</a>
        <a class="m4" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

        <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL1" />
        <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL2" />
        <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL3" />    
        <img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" class="HL4" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi MichaelvE,  Thank you for the reply. I did what you said and replace the "+" with a "~" and fix my html code. The changes works on my page but I was noticed the div were located in the wrong area than where I place them (using css). Is there a way to fix it so they are located where I put them using css? Also, I'm updating my original post with my new html code, so you can see how I have it coded now.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks MichaelvE for the help. I'm choosing your answer as the solution. I just need now to get my layout back to the way I had it setup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some wrong thing goes on let me guide you

1. `+` selector select element after you select in your case `.m1:hover + .HL1` mean select hl1 class after m1 class so it does not work as long your structure like that
2. there is no css selector that can select its parent so its not possible structure like that

> To me use some JS

here is some code without changing css but html

```css
.HL1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 330px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 565px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 800px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.HL4 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 1050px;
    height:50px;
    width: 150px;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.m1:Hover + .HL1 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m2:Hover + .HL2{
    visibility: visible;
    color:red
}

.m3:Hover + .HL3 {
    visibility: visible;
}

.m4:Hover + .HL4 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a id="Ms" align="center" class="m1">Home</a>
<div class="HL1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"  /></div>

<a class="m2" href="Bio.html">About</a>
<div  class="HL2" ><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/></div>

<a class="m3" href="Services.html">Services</a>
<div class="HL3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"  /></div>

<a class="m4" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

<div class="HL4" ><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by getting the layout back to the way you had it set up that you want the img tags to be in their own divs? If so, I have a solution below. If not, I'm not too sure what kind of layout you want to achieve.

```css
#Ms {
  text-align: center;
}

.HL1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 330px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.HL2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 565px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.HL3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 800px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.HL4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 1050px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.m1:Hover~.HL1 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.m2:Hover~.HL2 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.m3:Hover~.HL3 {
  visibility: visible;
}

.m4:Hover~.HL4 {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="Ms">
  <span class="m1">Home</span>
  <a class="m2" href="Bio.html">About</a>
  <a class="m3" href="Services.html">Services</a>
  <a class="m4" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>

  <div class="HL1"><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="HL2"><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="HL3"><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="HL4"><img src="../Online Portfolio site/images/header highlight.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @MIchaelvE, thank you for the reply. Sorry about the late reply.  Yes, you are correct. I'm trying to get the image div and the other element back to the way I setup them using css before the code, I was given moved everything around. I tried that code you gave me earlier and it moved the location of where the images show up and moved my one header image closer to my menu. I'm going to try this new code and see what happens. **Thank you very much for your new suggestion.**